# how to make WebP image from existing image files in php

Tags: php, image, php-extension, webp

I know there are packages in Laravel like [this](https://github.com/buglinjo/laravel-webp) for converting `PNG`/`JPG` images to `WebP` but this package is in php7.1 so we cannot use it for technical reasons, there is also an `imagewebp()` function in [php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagewebp.php) which we would like to use it, but I cannot find any documentation for how to read an already existing image and give it to the function to convert it to the WebP image. Does any one have a solution on  how to read an image file and give it convert it to the WebP images using the PHP extensions?